# How to multiply a numpy tuple array by scalar array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tuples

I have a numpy array A of shape(N,2) and a numpy array S of shape(N).

How do I multiply both arrays? Currently I am using this code:

```
tupleS = numpy.zeros( (N , 2) )
tupleS[:,0] = S
tupleS[:,1] = S
product = A * tupleS
```

I am a python beginner. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Numpy uses row-major order, so you have to explicitly create a column. As in:

```
>> A = numpy.array(range(10)).reshape(5, 2)
>>> B = numpy.array(range(5))
>>> B
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> A * B
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
>>> B = B.reshape(5, 1)
>>> B
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4]])
>>> A * B
array([[ 0,  0],
       [ 2,  3],
       [ 8, 10],
       [18, 21],
       [32, 36]])
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `reshape` creates a view, not a copy: `>>> s = numpy.arange(5); s.reshape(5, 1)[3,0] = 99; repr(s)` -> `'array([ 0,  1,  2, 99,  4])'`. So you could just do `A * B.reshape(5, 1)` without altering `B`.

Answer (score 3):

Essentially the same as @senderle's answer, but does not require an in-place manipulation of S.  You can get a slice an array in a way that adds axes with the index `None` and this will multiply them: `A * S[:,None]`.

```
>>> S = np.arange(5)
>>> S
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> A = np.arange(10).reshape((5,2))
>>> A
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [6, 7],
       [8, 9]])
>>> S[:,None]
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4]])
>>> A * S[:,None]
array([[ 0,  0],
       [ 2,  3],
       [ 8, 10],
       [18, 21],
       [32, 36]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
product = A * S
```

Comment: +1, using numpy's broadcasting features is always the way to go.

Comment: @Stiefel, @MRAB, I think the problem is that you have to reshape `S` for [broadcasting to work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573166/python-numpy-multiplicate-tuple-by-scalar/6573533#6573533).

Comment: Right, A*S does not work due to shape mismatch. Reshape is indeed the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Al tough the title of your question is slightly misnomer, I think the problem you have encountered is mainly related on the `numpy` [broadcasting rules](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html). Thus the following will not work (as you already have observed):

```
In []: N= 5
In []: A= rand(N, 2)
In []: A.shape
Out[]: (5, 2)

In []: S= rand(N)
In []: S.shape
Out[]: (5,)

In []: A* S
------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython console>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,2) (5)
```

However, now a simple way to make `S` compatible with broadcasting rules (of element wise product of `A* S`), is to expand its dimension, like:

```
In []: A* S[:, None]
Out[]: 
array([[ 0.54216549,  0.04964989],
       [ 0.41850647,  0.4197221 ],
       [ 0.03790031,  0.76744563],
       [ 0.29381325,  0.53480765],
       [ 0.0646535 ,  0.07367852]])
```

But this is really nothing but syntactical sugar for [expand_dims](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html), like:

```
In []: expand_dims(S, 1).shape
Out[]: (5, 1)
```

Anyway, I personally prefer this simple hassle free approach:

```
In []: S= rand(N, 1)
In []: S.shape
Out[]: (5, 1)

In []: A* S
Out[]: 
array([[ 0.40421854,  0.03701712],
       [ 0.63891595,  0.64077179],
       [ 0.03117081,  0.63117954],
       [ 0.24695035,  0.44950641],
       [ 0.14191946,  0.16173008]])
```

Thus with `python`; it's more straightforward to be explicit than implicit.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the title. Good answer. I accepted senderles answer because it is the simplest. All answer somehow aim to modify the shape to (N,1).

Answer (score -1):

I can think of:

```
product = A * numpy.tile(S, (2,1)).T
```

A faster solution might be:

```
product = [d * S for d in A.T]
```

though that doesn't get you a numpy array as output, and it's transposed. So to get a similar numpy array (note that this is slower than the first solution):

```
product = numpy.array([d * S for d in A.T]).T
```

There's probably a dozen other valid solutions, including better ones than these...